# able to read two files simultaneously

Tags: bash, file, unix, io-redirection

I want to output the following from fileA and fileB:

```
fileA: a b c d e
fileB: 1\t2\t3\ta b c d e
fileA: f g h i j
fileB: 4\t5\t6\tf g h i j
fileA: k l m n o
fileB: 7\t8\t9\tk l m n o
```

However, my script is outputting the following (and I cannot figure out why):

```
fileA: a b c d e
fileB: 1\t2\t3\ta b c d e\n1 2 3 a b c d e
fileA: f g h i j
fileB: 4\t5\t6\tf g h i j\n4 5 6 f g h i j
fileA: k l m n o
fileB: 7\t8\t9\tk l m n o\n7 8 9 k l m n o
```

fileA:

```
a b c d e
f g h i j
k l m n o
```

fileB:

```
1<tab>2<tab>3<tab>a b c d e
4<tab>5<tab>6<tab>f g h i j
7<tab>8<tab>9<tab>k l m n o
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
    read A <&3
    read B <&4
    [  -z "${A}" -a -z "${B}" ] && break
    echo "fileA: ${A}"
    echo "fileB: ${B}"
done 3<fileA 4<fileB
```

Note that `<tab>` refers to an actual tab in the file.

Comment: It works for me also. Does one of your files have funny line endings?

Comment: if either file has passed thru a windows based system, best to convert line-endings to Unix format with `dos2unix file [file2 ....]`. Good luck.

Comment: This is very weird. I actually wrote the exact fileA and fileB I have here, and the exact script here (all in Unix). I typed them in emacs. @merlin2011 - what sort of funny line endings should I expect?

Comment: @shelter - I tried "dos2unix fileA" and "dos2unix fileB", but still get same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading like this:

```
read -u 3 A
read -u 4 B
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I'm an idiot. There was an extra echo statement in the while loop (which I forgot to comment out in my code).